# Как узнать, что пользователь перешел на другую страницу сайта?

Tags: сессия, php

Помогите. Нужно узнать, сколько страниц просмотрел пользователь за одну сессию и время проведенное на этих страницах (за исключением последней).

Вопрос с временем понятен, нужно получить разницу между временем первого захода на страницу и последнего.

Не очень понимаю, как определить, что совершился переход на другую страницу.

Comment: > и время проведенное на этих страницах

Bad news: в браузерах изобрели вкладки, поэтому по данным чисто переходов по ссылкам эта оценка будет очень неточной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['page'][$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']])){
  $_SESSION['page'][$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['page'][$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]++;

//---
//Получение общего числа страниц:
print(array_sum($_SESSION['page']));
//Получение числа уникальных страниц:
print(count($_SESSION['page']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вам надо попробовать использовать Google Analytics и те отчёты, что он предоставляет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Все ссылки на сайте вы пускаете через свой враппер типа `<a href="goto.php?new_link=url">link</a>`. А в goto.php писать в сессию и время и на какие страницы ходит пользователь, и делать редирект потом на урл.
2. В серверном коде у скриптов выставлять, скажем, `$link = "script_name"`, вставить скрипт, который будет писать в сессию всё, что надо.